# which way is better to change TextView's height dynamically

Tags: android, textview

the textview is in a container view and its height is changing. In detail, the container is a relativeLayout with a few children and textView is one of them. The textView is a overlay and needs to be same height as the container.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

somehow the textView's height does not work in the xml, and it shows only with the text's height. Tried a few ways and do not work.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:text="text"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#eeffffff"
        />
```

seems do it in code is the only choice.

```
    containerView.measure(0, 0);
    int containerHeight = containerView.getHeight();
```

which one is better?

```
    theTextView.setHeight(containerHeight);
```

or

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = theTextView.getLayoutParams();
    param.height = containerHeight;
    theTextView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a

> RelativeLayout

and setting the parameter

> android:layoutHeight="wrap_content"

I would use a LinearLayout and set the height param to "match_parent"

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layoutHeight="match_parent"
   android:layoutWidth="match_parent">

   <TextView
      android:layoutHeight="match_parent"
      android:layoutWidth="match_parent">
   </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically the parent Layout has to take up the whole screen in order for the child TextView to take up the entire screen, so the Layout needs to be the proper size, then you can have the TextView "match_parent" to take up the entire Layout. I would stay away from RelativeLayout unless you have to have it, because a relative layout isn't as structured as a LinearLayout and at times harder to position properly.

Comment: thanks Anthony!, yes it has to be RelativeLayout here to make the TextView a overlay to cover whole RelativeLayout's other children.